# Calling function in view of cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have one team array and want that team name every where to show team name.It is possible to built a global function which can return team name and I call that function from my view means ctp file.

Answer (score 6):

```
please try this for west:

<?php
// controller name like app,users
// action name like getdata should be in controller
// and you can send parameter also
$output = $this->requestAction('controllerName/actionName/'.$parameter);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple approaches to this. What I cannot tell from your description is exactly what you are looking for. If it is simply to create an array of items that is accessible in your views, I would put it in app_controller.php

```
var $teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');

beforeFilter() {
   $this->set('teams', $this->teams);
}
```

Then in your view, you can access the array by the variable: $teams

If you only want to call teams on certain views, it may not be a good idea to set this variable for EVERYTHING. You can get around it by setting up a function in app controller.

```
function get_teams_array() {
   $teams = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');
   return $teams;
}
```

Then put together an element that will call this function:
views/elements/team.ctp

```
<?php
$teams = $this->requestAction(
             array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'teams'),
             array('return')
          );

/** process team array here as if it were in the view **/
?>
```

Then you can just call the element from your view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('team'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your /app/config/bootstrap.php file something like:

```
Configure::write('teams', array('team1', 'team2'));
```

Then everywhere you can get that array with:

```
$teams = Configure::read('teams');
```

and use it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing it to the configuration object?  I usually just define things in the bootstrap file as constants, e.g., define( TEAMS, array(...) );

Comment: I don't think it's possible to define array as a constant - Constants may only evaluate to scalar values (warning on the screen). Read the description here http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class and you will see that the cake team encourage to use it instead of variables and constants.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.*, you can use Helpers.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers

1 - Create your helper inside **src/View/Helper**:

```
/* src/View/Helper/TeamHelper.php */
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;

class TeamHelper extends Helper
{
    public function getName($id)
    {
        // Logic to return the name of them based on $id
    }
}
```

2 - Once you’ve created your helper, you can load it in your views.
Add the call `$this->loadHelper('Team');` inside **/src/View/AppView.php**:

```
/* src/View/AppView.php */
class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper('Team');
    }
}
```

3 - Once your helper has been loaded, you can use it in your views:

```
<?= $this->Team->getName($id) ?>
```