# where to create and how to call a function in view -- cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

For example I have a view calculate.ctp and inside that I want to call a function add(7,5); then of course it will display the output.

where will I create the function

```
function add($num1, $num2)
{
 $ans = $num1 + $num2;
 return $ans;
}
```

and how can I call that function in the calculate.ctp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its better create a helper for your common functions and put your common functions inside this helper

Comment: but how can I create a helper? I don't have the time to read and search about it in google. can you please give me a code snippet?

Comment: which version of cakephp your using

Answer (score 0):

/app/Config/boostrap.php is a useful place to add global functions.

Alternatively, have you thought about wrapping the functionality in a Helper?

Comment: okey thanks for the idea.. maybe I'll just read about that article. I'm new to cakephp so I on the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.*, you can use Helpers too.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165754/935330